# oData call to SuccessFactors Authentication

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am having trouble authenticating my `oData` call to success factors and I'm not completely sure why. Here is my code:

```
var username = "username";                          
var pwd = window.btoa("password");
console.log(pwd);
var empUrl = gadgets.io.getProxyUrl("https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com/odata/v2/EmpJob?&$format=json");                          
var empModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(empUrl,true,username,password);
empModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(data){
    console.log(data);                              
});
```

I receive 401 error for authentication but the username and the password are correct, I checked using postman app for chrome. Is there any issue with my code?

Comment: maybe there are unknown string-parts in your url, maybe it helps to encode() or decode() the url?

Comment: `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` does not expect the parameters you provided. You have to authenticate yourself in a different way. For example, you can add basic authentication to the headers in the `JSONModel.loadData` method.